# Настройка FTP Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, dhcp

Поднял на виртуальной машине с Ubuntu FTP-сервер. Она (виртуальная машина) получает динамический ip-адрес от DHCP-сервера, запущенного на роутере.

Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом подключении к этому FTP-серверу не нужно было проверять какой у него в данный момент ip?

В сетях не силен, пишу сразу.

Comment: Вы бы пояснили подробнее, что вам надо?

Comment: Мне нужно подключаться к виртуальной машине через фтп с основной оси,на виртуалке стоит убунту,фтп сервер на нем настроил,вот только айпи на ней меняется и каждый раз смотреть какой айпи и прописывать при коннекте не особо удобно,можно ли сделать как то его статическим?

Comment: Вам нужно или настроить ваш dhcp-сервер так, чтобы он выдавал Ubuntu всегда один и тот же ip, или назначить ей статический ip в настройках интерфейса.

Comment: Спасибо сейчас поищу как это сделать!

Comment: Почитал про то что вы мне посоветовали,не совсем понял где это все настроить,на роутере? Или в настройках вирт машины.Я так понимаю если отключить DHCP на роутере,у всех устройств которые будут конектится к роутеру будет один и тот же айпи?

Comment: Если отключить DHCP на роутере - то каждое устройство должно само знать свой ip. Например, ip должен быть прописан в настройках интерфейса статическим.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо добиться того, чтобы ваш FTP-сервер всегда имел один и тот же ip-адрес в сети.

Решить этот вопрос можно несколькими путями:

1) Использовать статический ip-адрес в настройках интерфейса:

```
# В /etc/network/interfaces прописать:

iface eth0 inet static 
address 192.168.0.1 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.0.254
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.254 8.8.8.8
auto eth0
```

Подробнее [по ссылке](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E#%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8).

2) Настроить dhcp-сервер таким образом, чтобы закрепить за определённым MAC-адресом определённый ip.

Как это сделать зависит от от того, где и какой у вас запущен dhcp-сервер. Например, мой роутер Zyxel позволяет через собственный веб-интерфейс выполнить подобную настройку так:

[image: настройка dhcp zyxel]

3) Наверняка есть и другие способы, но мне они неизвестны. Может более сведущие гуру помогут.

Comment: Можно ещё попробовать использовать Avahi, и обращаться к VM по имени. Тем более, что в Ubuntu, вроде как, Avahi уже установлен по умолчанию.

Comment: Надо попробовать!